# Syntax for PFObject saveInBackground progressBlock

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, swift5

What is the Swift5 Syntax for Parse PFObject saveInBackground progressBlock? I get error "Incorrect argument labels in call (have _:progressBlock, expected withTarget:selector). The Parse documentation appears not up to date. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
let imageData = image.pngData()!
let imageFileObject = PFFileObject(name: "image.png", data: imageData)
let userPhoto = PFObject(className: "ARReferenceImages")
userPhoto["imageName"] = "Test 1"
userPhoto["imageFileObject"] = imageFileObject

userPhoto.saveInBackground ({ (success: Bool, error: Error?) in       // Xcode error here
        if (success) {
            print("image saved to cloud")
        } else if error != nil {
            print("error saving data to cloud")
        }
    }, progressBlock: { (percentDone: Int32) in
        // code to update progress bar spinner here
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PFObject` does not have `progressBlock`. `PFFile` is the one that has. You should use it like this:

```swift
let imageData = image.pngData()!
let imageFileObject = PFFileObject(name: "image.png", data: imageData)
imageFileObject.saveInBackground ({ (success: Bool, error: Error?) in       // Xcode error here
    if (success) {
        let userPhoto = PFObject(className: "ARReferenceImages")
        userPhoto["imageName"] = "Test 1"
        userPhoto["imageFileObject"] = imageFileObject
        userPhoto.saveInBackground { (succeeded, error)  in
            if (succeeded) {
                // The object has been saved.
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }
    } else if error != nil {
            print("error saving data to cloud")
    }
}, progressBlock: { (percentDone: Int32) in
    // code to update progress bar spinner here
})
```